# Does this KL divergence inequality hold?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, gm.general-mathematics, geometric-probability

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are two discrete distributions. Given a positive constant $\beta\in(0,1)$, we create a new discrete distribution $y$ such that
$$
\frac{y\left( x \right)}{p\left( x \right)}=\frac{\left( \frac{q\left( x \right)}{p\left( x \right)} \right) ^{1-\beta}}{\mathbb{E} _{x\sim p}\left[ \left( \frac{q\left( x \right)}{p\left( x \right)} \right) ^{1-\beta} \right]},
$$
or equivalently
$$
y\left( x \right) =\frac{q\left( x \right) ^{1-\beta}p\left( x \right) ^{\beta}}{\sum_x{q\left( x \right) ^{1-\beta}p\left( x \right) ^{\beta}}}.
$$
Under these conditions, can this inequality
$$
\mathrm{KL}\left( y\parallel q \right) \ge \beta\, \mathrm{KL}\left( p\parallel q \right) 
$$
hold? If not, what's the counter-example?

Comment: Inequalities close to this hold, but I don't have time to check this one. See [Annealing Between Distributions by Averaging Moments](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2013/file/fb60d411a5c5b72b2e7d3527cfc84fd0-Paper.pdf).
They show that the distribution $y$ that minimizes

$$f(y) :=(1-\beta)\mathsf{KL}(y||q) +\beta \mathsf{KL}(y||p)$$

takes the form $y\propto q^{1-\beta}p^\beta$.
We then have that

$$f(q) \geq f(y)\implies \beta \mathsf{KL}(q||p) \geq (1-\beta)\mathsf{KL}(y||q)+\beta\mathsf{KL}(y||p).$$

I don't know if a modified argument can get your inequality.

Comment: Also note that your KL between a distribution and a geometric mixture has been studied in other places, e.g. [here](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/21/5/485/htm), where it is computed for geometric mixtures of Gaussians. I think the content of that paper is enough to check your inequality for Gaussians. I would recommend doing this (it should be quite quick), as it may be sufficient to produce a quick counterexample to your inequality.

Comment: Couldn't prove it but in case is useful I got that $\mathrm{KL}(y||q)\ge\beta\mathrm{KL}(pq||q)$, Wikipedia list the next form of the Hölder's ineq:

$
(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^r|y_k|^s)^{r+s}\le(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{r+s})^{r}( \sum_{k=1}^n |y_k|^{r+s})^{s}$ for $(r,s)\in\mathbb{R}_+,
$

setting $x_k=q(x),y_k=p(x),r=1-\beta,s=\beta$ we get,

$
\sum_{x=1}^n q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta\le(\sum_{x=1}^n q(x))^{1-\beta}( \sum_{x=1}^n p(x))^{1-\beta}=1\cdot 1=1
\Rightarrow\frac{q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta}{\sum_{x=1}^n q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta}\ge q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta
$

Therefore:

Comment: $
\mathrm{KL}(y||q)\\
=\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta}{\sum_{x=1}^n q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta}\ln \frac{q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta}{\sum_{x=1}^n q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta}\\
\ge \sum_{x=1}^n q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta\ln q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta\\
\ge \sum_{x=1}^n q(x)p(x)\ln q(x)^{1-\beta}p(x)^\beta\\
=\sum_{x=1}^n (q(x)p(x)\ln p(x)^\beta+(1-\beta)q(x)p(x)\ln q(x))\qquad (q(x)<1\Rightarrow \ln q(x)<0)\\
\ge \sum_{x=1}^n q(x)p(x)\ln p(x)^\beta\\
=\beta\sum_{x=1}^n q(x)p(x)\ln p(x)\\
=\beta\sum_{x=1}^n q(x)p(x)\ln \frac{q(x)p(x)}{q(x)}\\
=\beta\mathrm{KL}(pq||q)\\
$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is a counter-example provided by Iosif Pinelis : p=(1/2,1/2) q= (1/100,99/100), \beta=0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., if $p_1=1/2$, $p_2=1/2$, $q_1=1/100$, $q_2=99/100$, and $\beta=1/10$, then the ratio of the left-hand side of the conjectured inequality to its right-hand is $0.00877\ldots<1$.

---

Jiacai Liu [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455122/does-this-kl-divergence-inequality-hold/455167#comment1178386_455167) if the conjectured inequality holds in the opposite direction. The answer to this is also no. E.g., if $p_1=1/1000$, $p_2=999/1000$, $q_1=9/10$, $q_2=1/10$, and $\beta=6/10$, then the ratio of the left-hand side of the conjectured inequality to its right-hand is $1.5006\ldots>1$.

Comment: Thanks for your counter-example. It's very helpful to me.

Comment: I wonder whether this  inequality always hold for the inverse direction ? That is KL(y || q ) <=  \beta * KL(p || q)

Comment: @JiacaiLiu : The answer to this is also no. I have added details on this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Since the conjectured inequality does not hold in the opposite direction,  can  we find a function of $\beta$ and replace the $\beta$ in the RHS of  the conjectured inequality with it so that the new inequality can hold in the opposite direction ?  For example,  the new inequality can be  $KL(y || q ) \le \sqrt{\beta} * KL(p || q)$

Comment: @JiacaiLiu : I suggest you post your latter question in a separate post.

Comment: OK, thanks again.